# How to set precision for complex numbers in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code where I need to add two complex numbers. Formula is working, however, I am not able to get rid of the scientific notation. I'm new to C++, and not sure how to use setPrecision.

My code in .hpp:

```
    class ComplexNumber
    {
    public:

//--constructors
    ComplexNumber();
    ComplexNumber(double r, double i);
    ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber &cn);

    void print();
    ComplexNumber add(const ComplexNumber &rhs);
    private:
        double re, im;
    };
```

My code in .cpp file

```
//--constructors
ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber()
{

}
ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(double r, double i)
{

}
ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber &cn)
{

}    

void ComplexNumber::print()
    {
        std::cout << this->re << " + " << this->im << "i" << std::endl;
    }

    ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::add(const ComplexNumber &rhs)
    {
        return ComplexNumber(this-> re + rhs.re, this->im + rhs.im);
    }
```

My main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    ComplexNumber a(1,2);
    ComplexNumber b(3,4);
    ComplexNumber c;

    c = a.add(b);
    c.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
4.94066e-324 + 6.95322e-310i

it should be 4 + 6i

Comment: Where is your two-argument constructor?

Comment: are you sure your calculations are correct? these values seem far off.

Comment: It seems you have worse problems than with the precision. Are you sure your `add` function really works? It almost seem like you have some *undefined behavior* somewhere.

Comment: Both of the value you show are very close to 0, meaning very far from the right answer.  Did you post the same code that you're using with the answer it gave?  For example, I don't see the constructor that you called.

Comment: `4.94066e-324` is not even close to 4, that's more like 0. Please [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] as the code you show looks fine.

Comment: Btw, if you are doing this for some reason other than being bored or for an assignment, C++ already has `std::complex`.

Comment: And the constructor implementation please? Also, you don't need your own copy constructor: the compiler will generate one for you.

Comment: constructor implementation is added.

Comment: Where? All you've done is added the declarations.

Comment: Now you stare at those constructor definitions intensely or explain them to your rubber duck. If that does not help, reread the relevant section in your learning material.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. At the time of writing, both answers are correct.

Answer (score 2):

None of your constructors actually *do* anything. That means the member variables will be uninitialized, their values will be indeterminate and using them will lead to *undefined behavior*

You need to actually initialize the members in the constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Works as expected after fixing the syntax (making it an aggregate):

```
#include <iostream>

struct ComplexNumber
{
    void print();
    ComplexNumber add(const ComplexNumber &rhs);
    double re, im;
};

void ComplexNumber::print()
{
    std::cout << this->re << " + " << this->im << "i" << std::endl;
}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::add(const ComplexNumber &rhs)
{
    return ComplexNumber{this-> re + rhs.re, this->im + rhs.im};
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    ComplexNumber a{1,2};
    ComplexNumber b{3,4};
    ComplexNumber c;

    c = a.add(b);
    c.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But do note that if a refactorer changes the `struct` to `double im, re;`, for example, then merry hell will ensue. Nice answer though, plus one.

Answer (score 1):

*Precision* is **not** the issue here.

Your two-argument constructor needs to be implemented as follows

```
ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(double r, double i) : re(r), im(i)
{
}
```

otherwise the class members stay *uninitialised*.

Reading uninitialised variables is undefined behaviour in C++; your output is a manifestation of that.

It's stylistically acceptable (and in my opinion *preferable* for a number class) to write

```
ComplexNumber() = default;
```

for your default constructor; if you want it to keep the class members uninitialised, as is the case for the C++ built-in types. Just don't *read* the member variables before assigning them to something.

Finally, rely on the compiler to generate the copy constructor for you: there's no need to build your own.

Comment: Very detailed explanation. Works as expected! Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Do study the `= default` notation. Not everyone on this site will agree with me on this particular point; it might be safer to set the members to zero in the default constructor.

Comment: You can get initialized members with the `ComplexNumber() = default;` syntax via in-class member initializers if you want to.